# How to set the titles of different tabs in a UITabBarController?

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, uitabbarcontroller

I have the following tabs in a TabBarApplication. I navigate from my home page to this TabBar.

```
UIViewController *viewController1 = [[ExpenseRecorderViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ExpenseRecorderViewController" bundle:nil];

UIViewController *viewController2 = [[TaxCalculatorViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TaxCalculatorViewController" bundle:nil];

UIViewController *viewController3 = [[CurrencyConverterViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CurrencyConverterViewController" bundle:nil];

UIViewController *viewController4 = [[emiCalculatorViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"emiCalculatorViewController" bundle:nil];

self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:viewController1, viewController2,viewController3, viewController4, nil];
```

Now if I try to set the titles of theses four tabs by something like -

```
[[tabBarController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0] setTitle:@"title A"];
[[tabBarController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:1] setTitle:@"title B"];
[[tabBarController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:2] setTitle:@"title C"];
```

then it does not work. I think I need to set the title of the navigation bar at the top. But how to do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Programmatically Setting UITabBar Titles](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6056354/programmatically-setting-uitabbar-titles)

Answer (score 0):

Should do this:

```
appDelegate.newsNavController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:newsViewController] autorelease];
    appDelegate.newsNavController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    appDelegate.newsNavController.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"IdCard.png"];
    appDelegate.newsNavController.tabBarItem.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Title_News", @"");
```